# Getting this Error uploading multiple apk files in google play store

Tags: android, google-play

**Error: APK version  3404400,2802221,2401211 supports all the same devices as other APKs with higher versions. It would not be served. Please deactivate an APK.**

Previously I have uploaded multiple apks for my android application with version 1.1

versioncode     screenresolution
3404400           720x1280

2802221           320x480

2401211           240x320

Now Today When I have uploaded with versioncode 5404400,4802221,4401211 for respective screen resolutions with version 1.2 . Then I am getting this error. Now I have deactivated those older apks. Is there will be any problem in getting updates notification for devices(who already installed the older version) . Please let me know.

Comment: no, this is the main idea. To have only one active apk for particular constraints. Your user will be up to date :)

Comment: I am not getting the update notification in my mobile. What might be the reason?????

Comment: depends on your settings. If you visit your app in play store, what do you see - Update or Install button? Also check the official information provided by google: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html

Comment: I am getting Update button while visiting the app in play store. But just like in other apps, we are getting notification from play store to download the update version. That I am not getting. Because right now my older version apks are also active, Is that might be the reason????? Should I deactivate them???

Comment: i've never left two active versions for one app. I don't know the behavior. Probably you should deactivate the older ones.

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot for your valuable guidance. But I have done this app with multiple apk. Now when I will deactive the older ones, devices having the older version of that app. They will get the updates notification or not????? Will surely not face any problem....

Answer (score 0):

Solved by de activating the older ones